# How to compile string html template?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to compile a string html template that's dynamically generated and then insert that compiled output with correct bindings to my page.

I haven't been able to find the correct way to do this in AngularDart 0.14.0 (so many breaking changes between versions....)

This is what I have, but the `template(childScope, childInjector, [inner])` line is invalid and expects a `DirectiveInjector` which I don't know how

```dart
void onShadowRoot(Node shadowRoot) {
    Element tbody = pgtElement.querySelector(".pg-body");
    String html = '<tr ng-repeat="item in cmp.data">';
    for(PgTableColumnComponent td in this.tds){
        html += '<td>' + td.template + '</td>';
    }
    html += '</tr>';
    tbody.appendHtml(html);

    ViewFactory template = compiler([tbody], directives);
    Scope childScope = scope.createChild(scope.context);

    Injector childInjector = injector.createChild([new Module()..bind(Scope, toValue: childScope)]);
    Template(childScope, childInjector, [tbody]);
}
```

I also am wanting be be able to access the component scope in the new compiled code, for example the `ng-repeat="item in cmp.data"`